# Swift - Navigation Controller problems on dynamic TableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

So, I'm having a bit of an issue with my Navigation Controller. Below is a picture from my story board. Let's number the different tableviews from left to right 1, 2, 3, 4. Tableview 1 is the root one with the navigation controller attached, and tableview 4 is furthest to the right. The white(blank) view controller above is the basket:

[image]

When I run the application, the root tableview looks as I'd expect:

[image]

If you click the first cell 'Classic Starters' you are taken to tableview controller number 2 which also looks as I'd expect, full access to my basket and the option to go back to the main menu:

[image]

Now the next tableview number 3 is where the problem is. If you click 'Dips' from tableview controller 2 above you are taken to the tableview number 3. As you can see, there is no basket button available, and again if you proceed further to tableview 4 still no basket button:

[image]

What I've tried:

I've tried dragging a segue attachment from the navigation controller in the top left to the third tableview controller, but still no luck. I've tried embedding tvc 3 and 4 in their own navigation controllers but still, no luck. I'm clearly doing something stupid here, so I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: How do you segue to the next view controller?  I can't see any segues in your storyboard for them beyond the first. You probably don't need so many scenes anyway; you could use reuse the same view controller scene with a different data source.

Comment: let destinationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TypeItemsTVC") as! TypeItemsTableViewController
            destinationViewController.incomeType = self.itemSelected
            destinationViewController.incomeDesc = self.itemDesc
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)

Comment: I use different views because all confrom to different sets of protocols. It was just neater at the time

Comment: You should edit your question to include your code.

Comment: I'll do that now, sorry.  I thought it was an XCode storyboard issue rather than a problem with my code.  Give me 5 :D

Comment: Custom bar button ? in Each viewController ?